# Designing a library that contains multiple redux instances

Tags: architecture, redux

I have a design question for you while using redux.

The main purpose is to expose a Library which supports the logic of our application and leaves the UI implementation to the library user. This library will have to communicate with several services and also receives push events from external sources.

Our library was first designed as using redux + plain javascript. As we developed the architecture further we struggled with an issue that is haunting us in one other application: we might have different teams working on this library. This fact adds complexity to our development/deployment process.

We then tried to solve this with the following:

- Having multiple "instances" of redux (one for each team)
- Having a much smaller common codebase that contains the API and the async push events
- A call to the API or an external event triggers an action in every instance of redux
- New states are grouped together in the common codebase

At the cost of a bit of overengineering, this would enable us to have different codebases for each team and individual deploy processes (Except for the common repo which would have to be synced but much more straightforward and less prone to changes).

Do you think this is viable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that having multiple stores is not the best solution. I think it would be better to have each team have their own library of their set of constants, action creators, and reducers, which would be used in a single store. This would make developing cross-team integrations much easier, and the code base would end up being more consistent. The biggest thing is making the view layer more consistent and flexible. You don't want to have a ton of different `<Provider />`s. Its better to have multiple smart components.

I don't think that having extrnal connectors and listeners between applications would be worth the complexity. There is some upside there because then you totally eliminate the possibility of conflicts (though i think you can probably do this in the way i described too).

API methods should be encapsulated outside of redux anyways, so in either case that should work the same. Action creators should import their async functions, rather than use `fetch` themselves.